# Why is adding a transition on the body element stopping my backdrop-filter from working on the nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I added a simple page load animation and it is causing the backdrop-filter effect I have on my nav from working correctly.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--dracula-background);
    color: var(--dracula-foreground);
    background: linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        var(--dracula-background) 50%,
        var(--dracula-greypurple) 100%
    );
    animation: fadeInAnimation ease 0.3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```css
.nav-desktop {
    background-color: rgba(56, 58, 89, 0.8);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%);
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 4px rgba(50, 52, 75, 0.6);
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1.2rem 0 1.2rem 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

The nav only gets the slight transparency I have set from the background-color, but the backdrop-filter isn't doing anything on the nav or any other component using blur.

Comment: Could you please share some markup so I could try to recreate your issue?

Comment: I think it would probably be easier to see the full HTML - https://github.com/stephanlamoureux/v1/blob/main/index.html

Comment: You should add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of linking in external sources.

Comment: I did feel naughty doing that, just seemed like a lot of markup to post 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue, but I would love to know *why* this is the case. By changing the `animation-fill-mode` to none, the blur works...